# max-delivery-attempts does not work for un-acknowledged messages

Tags: activemq-artemis

I noted strange behavior in Artemins. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I don't understand something.
I use Artemis Core API. I set `autoCommitAcks`  to `false`. I noted that If message is received in `MessageHandler` but message is not acknowledged and session is rollbacked then Artemis does not consider this message as undelivered, Artemis consider this message as not sent to consumer at all. Parameter **max-delivery-attempts** does not work in this case. Message is redelivered an infinite number of times. Method `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientMessage#getDeliveryCount` returns 1 each time. Message has `false` value in **Redelivered** column in web console. If message is acknowledged before session rollback then **max-delivery-attempts** works properly.

What exactly is the purpose of message acknowledge? Acknowledge means only that message was received or acknowledge means that message was received and processed successfully? Maybe I can use acknowledge in both ways and it only depends on my requirements?

By message acknowledge I mean calling `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientMessage#acknowledge` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is expected.

Core clients actually consume messages from a *local* buffer which is filled with messages from the broker asynchronously. The amount of message data in this local buffer is controlled by the `consumerWindowSize` set on the client's URL. The broker may dispatch many thousands of messages to various clients that sit in these local buffers and are *never* actually seen in any capacity by the consumers. These messages are considered to be *in delivery* and are not available to other clients, but they are *not* considered to be *delivered*. Only when a message is acknowledged is it considered to be delivered to a client.

If the client is auto-committing acknowledgements then acknowledging a message will quickly remove it from its respective queue. Once the message is removed from the queue it can no longer be redelivered because it doesn't exist anymore on the broker. In short, you can't get configurable redelivery semantics if you auto-commit acknowledgements.

However, if the client is *not* auto-committing acknowledgements and the consumer closes (for any reason) without committing the acknowledgements or calls `rollback()` on its `ClientSession` then the acknowledged messages will be redelivered according to the configured redelivery semantics (including `max-delivery-attempts`).

Comment: I do not know how I can use  the configured redelivery semantics  when I use auto-committing acknowledgements. If message is acknowledged then message is consider as delivered whether session is committed or rollbacked. If message is not acknowledged and session is rollbacked then message will be redelivered infinite number of times.  So redelivery semantics  is used only when auto-committing acknowledgement is turned off.

Comment: I updated my answer to make things more clear. Hope that helps. If my answer addressed your question please mark it as correct to help others who have this same question in the future. Thanks!